# Create coupon code programmatically (in Magento 2.x)

Tags: magento2, database, error, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon

I'm trying to port over tens of thousands of coupons from a custom e-commerce website into Magento 2.0.8 and I'm having a hard time getting it to work. These are simple coupons either fixed $ or % off of the carts subtotal. I have been unable to get it to save from the command line.

I have a command called coupons:migrate that I'm running this code in. This is what I have so far in my createCoupon method that accepts the current coupons row (looping over a CSV file):

```
protected function createCoupon($coupon) {
        $shoppingCartPriceRule = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule');

        $shoppingCartPriceRule->setName($coupon['name'])
            ->setDescription($coupon['name'])
            ->setFromDate($coupon['start'])
            ->setToDate($coupon['end'])
            ->setUsesPerCustomer($coupon['max_redemptions'])
            ->setCustomerGroupIds(array('0','1','2','3',))
            ->setIsActive('1')
            ->setSimpleAction($coupon['discount_type'])
            ->setDiscountAmount($coupon['discount_amount'])
            ->setDiscountQty(1)
            ->setApplyToShipping($coupon['flag_is_free_shipping'])
            ->setTimesUsed($coupon['redemptions'])
            ->setWebsiteIds(array('1',))
            ->setCouponType('2')
            ->setCouponCode($coupon['code'])
            ->setUsesPerCoupon(NULL);

    return $shoppingCartPriceRule->save();

}
```

I'm currently getting this error from my database:

```
[Zend_Db_Statement_Exception]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, query was: INSERT INTO `magento_reward_salesrule` (`rule_id`,`points_delta`) VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `points_delta` = VALUES
  (`points_delta`)

  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm basically stuck now.

Comment: How about your current issue?

Comment: @B.Mackswell, did the answer help you to solve the problem? If so, please accept the answer. If not, please inform us.

Answer (score 1):

Try code below

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');  

$coupon['name'] = 'test';
$coupon['desc'] = 'Discount for Test';
$coupon['start'] = date('Y-m-d');
$coupon['end'] = '';
$coupon['max_redemptions'] = 1;
$coupon['discount_type'] = 'by_percent';
$coupon['discount_amount'] = 15;
$coupon['flag_is_free_shipping'] = 'no';
$coupon['redemptions'] = 1;
$coupon['code'] = 'test-1234'; //this code will normally be autogenetated but i am hard coding for testing purposes

$shoppingCartPriceRule = $objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule');
$shoppingCartPriceRule->setName($coupon['name'])
    ->setDescription($coupon['desc'])
    ->setFromDate($coupon['start'])
    ->setToDate($coupon['end'])
    ->setUsesPerCustomer($coupon['max_redemptions'])
    ->setCustomerGroupIds(array('0','1','2','3',))
    ->setIsActive(1)
    ->setSimpleAction($coupon['discount_type'])
    ->setDiscountAmount($coupon['discount_amount'])
    ->setDiscountQty(1)
    ->setApplyToShipping($coupon['flag_is_free_shipping'])
    ->setTimesUsed($coupon['redemptions'])
    ->setWebsiteIds(array('1'))
    ->setCouponType(2)
    ->setCouponCode($coupon['code'])
    ->setUsesPerCoupon(NULL);
$shoppingCartPriceRule->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't try to test your code, however, seem that your code lines need to improve the performance. After saving the object model, we need to unset the data object:

```
$shoppingCartPriceRule->save()
$shoppingCartPriceRule->unsetData();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
protected $ruleFactory

public function __construct(\Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory $ruleFactory) {
    $this->rulesFactory = $ruleFactory }


$ruleData = [
            "name" => "Buy 3 tee shirts and get the 4th free",
            "description" => "Buy 3 tee shirts and get the 4th free",
            "from_date" => null,
            "to_date" => null,
            "uses_per_customer" => "0",
            "is_active" => "1",
            "stop_rules_processing" => "0",
            "is_advanced" => "1",
            "product_ids" => null,
            "sort_order" => "0",
            "simple_action" => "buy_x_get_y",
            "discount_amount" => "1.0000",
            "discount_qty" => null,
            "discount_step" => "3",
            "apply_to_shipping" => "0",
            "times_used" => "0",
            "is_rss" => "1",
            "coupon_type" => "NO_COUPON",
            "use_auto_generation" => "0",
            "uses_per_coupon" => "0",
            "simple_free_shipping" => "0",
            "customer_group_ids" => [0, 1, 2, 3],
            "website_ids" => [1],
            "coupon_code" => null,
            "store_labels" => [],
            "conditions_serialized" => '',
            "actions_serialized" => ''
        ];

$ruleModel = $this->ruleFactory->create();
$ruleModel->setData($ruleData);
$ruleModel->save();
```